# jQuery mobile and jQuery 2

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Today I'm updating my libraries. I noticed the 2.0.3 version of jQuery, and copied it to my project. However, I'm also using jQuery mobile 1.3.2, which doesn't seem to support the new jQuery. I had this problem before a few weeks ago, and hoped it would be fixed in the next jQuery patch, alas it isn't.

Everything works perfectly fine with jQuery mobile 2.0.3 and jQuery 1.10.2. Is this a known issue, or do you suspect I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not an issue.

jQuery Mobile is locked to certain jQuery versions.

If you take a look at an official link: http://blog.jquerymobile.com/2013/02/20/jquery-mobile-1-3-0-released/

You will find a text:

> Support for jQuery 1.9.1 (and 2.0.0)
>
> jQuery Mobile 1.3.0 supports versions of jQuery core 1.7.2 – 1.9.1 and we’re actively testing the upcoming 2.0 version too. We will be keeping in sync with their releases to let you take full advantage of the new goodness.

This also relates to subversions like 1.3.1 and 1.3.2.

Comment: Do you mean jQuery mobile intends not to use jQuery 2.0.3?

Comment: It is simply locked, version 1.4 will support last jQuery version but you will need to wait for it.